# How to avoid Pandas groupby caused data lost

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timeline

I have a dataframe type of data with a size of 7689 rows × 114 columns. In which it contains datetime, float type data, etc. I tried to use the 'groupby' method to divide the original data into 4 parts, after processing some basic subtraction operation separately (without changing the data structure) and combine the 4 parts back into one using the 'pd.concat' method.

But after I concatenate them back into one, the size became 7685 rows × 114 columns. And most importantly, it shows data missing when I visualize the DateTime as a timeline, originally it was a half a year consistent data, but now nearly a month missed(but the data amount increased at the meantime).
Here is the code:

```
#Divide into 4 parts according to column 1 and column 2
grouped = overlay_syco.groupby(['column 1','column 2'])
print(grouped.describe())

#print(grouped.describe())
l_grouped = list(grouped)

df1 = l_grouped[0][1]
df2 = l_grouped[1][1]
df3 = l_grouped[2][1]
df4 = l_grouped[3][1]

df_con0 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], axis=0)
```

this is the groupby result:

```
count   
column 1                                                      column 2          
row1 1.0                                                 1936.0   
           2.0                                                 1911.0   
row2 1.0                                                 1925.0   
           2.0                                                 1913.0
```

Any help to fix this I would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if you try extracting the length of the `l_grouped` variable:

`len(l_grouped)`

you'll find that it returns a value higher than 4. In other words, you are splitting the data into more than 4 parts, but are only putting 4 parts back together.

Comment: I just tried it but the return value is 4, so I figured it's not this issue.@mullinscr

Comment: Can you give some detail and data for your "basic subtraction operation?"